# Target every label elements that has the correct data-answer attributs with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a HTML code and I want to select each label that has the `data-anwser` set to "correct", how can I do it with pure Javascript? Here's my HTML

```
               <div class="form-group answer" role="group">
                    <label data-answer="correct">
                        <div>Test</div>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group answer" role="group">
                    <label data-answer="incorrect">
                        <div>Test</div>
                    </label>
                </div>
```

And here's the begining of what I tried with the JS

```
<script>
    var div = document.getElementsByClassName('answer');

    window.onload = (event) => {
        for (var i = 0; i < div.length; i++) {
            var label = div[i].getElementsByTagName('label');
            if (label[i].dataset == 'correct') {
                console.log("CORRECTE");
            } else {
                console.log("INCORECTE");
            }
            console.log(label[i].dataset);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Thank you:)

Comment: Why `label[i]`? Your `i` is for the `<div>`s, not the `<label>`s in each `<div>`.

Comment: Sorry, JS is not my cup of tea lmao, I'm better at PHP, HTML, CSS :P

Comment: Actually, I've did research before asking on Stackoverflow and didn't find sometime that helped me, I might have used the wrong keywords and stuff, sorry for that. I'm not a pro in Javascript at all, so be indulgent please!:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [query selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', ev => {

  const correctAnswers = document.querySelectorAll('.answer [data-answer="correct"]');
  correctAnswers.forEach(el => {
    el.classList.toggle('selected');
  });

});
```

```css
.form-group > label {
  margin: 0.33em;
  padding: 0.33em;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  background-color: silver;
  width: 250px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.form-group > label.selected {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 2px dotted black;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group answer" role="group">
  <label data-answer="correct">
    <div>Test 1</div>
  </label>
</div>
<div class="form-group answer" role="group">
  <label data-answer="incorrect">
    <div>Test 2</div>
  </label>
</div>
<div class="form-group answer" role="group">
  <label data-answer="correct">
    <div>Test 3</div>
  </label>
</div>

<button id="btn">highlight correct answers</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var answersCorrect = document.querySelectorAll("*[data-answer='correct']")

Array.from(answersCorrect).forEach(element => {
  console.log(element)
})
```

Comment: OP was asking about labels specifically, not anything with `data-answer` set to `"correct"`. Also, the `*` is unnecessary. Also, you can reference `console.log` directly in the `forEach` instead of using a redundant arrow function.

Comment: sorry my bad... wow I actually learn something new here 